# How can I collect all the version numbers in team-city subprojects and put them into one file

Tags: docker, teamcity

I am currently using TeamCity Enterprise 2022.04.1 (build 108575).

My current docker project is setup like this (version 1.1 as an example):

> ```
> Project
>  Step 1 - build and tag imageA to version 1.1
>  Step 2 - push imageA:1.1 to registry
>  Step 3 - build and tag imageB to version 1.1
>  Step 4 - push imageB:1.1 to registry
>  Step 5 - create docker compose env file with all the containers at version 1.1.
> ```

This could take up to an hour  to build so
I would like to create a new project with subprojects that would build like so (using version 1.x as an example):

> ```
> ProjectGlobal (version 1.x)   
>   ProjectImageA (build number 1.4)
>     Step 1 - build and tag imageA to version 1.4
>     Step 2 - push imageA:1.4 to registry   
>   ProjectImageB (build number 1.7)
>     Step 1 - build and tag imageB to version 1.7
>     Step 2 - push imageB:1.7 to registry   
>   ProjectCreateEnvFile (build number 1.10)
>     * Step 1 - create env file with (imageA:1.4, imageB:1.7)
> ```

Sometimes there will only be changes in imageA and sometimes only in imageB and sometimes in both so the versions can be different base on what changed.  They're in the same git repository.

- How do I create an env file with (imageA:1.4, imageB:1.7)